# Adding Variables to Variables

Tags: python, addition

```
a = input('1st number: ')
b = input('2nd number: ')
c = a + b
print(a + ' + ' + b + ' = ' + c)
```

If I enter 1 for a then 2 for b it returns 12 instead of 3 and I don't understand why it wont find the sum of the two variables. Could anyone help I started with Java and I'm new to Python.

Comment: inputs are strings by default, you need to convert them to integer with int(), see tons of other questions with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns a string. So basically you have `a = '1'`, `b = '2'` and `c = a + b = '12'`.

You need to cast `a` and `b` to int like `a = int(a)`, `b = int(b)` then you'd get `c = 3`